# Opencart - 'Add to cart' button adding x2 products to cart incorrectly

Tags: opencart, mmenu

I have a fresh install of Opencart 1.5.6.4 - link is [here](http://www.mercurysafety.com/mercury-spillage-kit/)

On all my product pages (not the category pages) - when you click 'add to cart' it adds x2 of everything.

I have tried re-creating a product with a new SEO title, title, product, new model number - but still, it adds it twice to my cart?

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set minimum quantity of your product? If yes, then it will add a minimum quantity automatically if user entered quantity less than minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - That would make perfect sense - however minimum quantity is set to 1 - this is applied to all products too not just individually

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i think you have made some mistake in integrating your product detail page. As i checked in console when i clicked `add to cart` button there are two same requests are passing each with single quantity. Which causes adding x2 product of your quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a conflict or bug with the ***mmenu*** jquery extension being used for your nav bar and being included as ***jquery.mmenu.min.all.js***.

Comment out the line:

```
$('nav#menu').mmenu();
```

And you'll see the cart button functions normally.  Unfortunately this breaks your nav bar. I wish I could tell you more but perhaps worth contacting the developer of that extension:

http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/support/problem-solving.html

or file an issue here:

https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues

Since you appear to be running the most recent version, if there is indeed a bug it hasn't been fixed yet.  I've gone ahead and added the ***mmenu*** tag to your question which hopefully may draw the attention of someone with answers. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

***[SOLVED]***

> On all my product pages (not the category pages) - when you click 'add
>   to cart' it adds x2 of everything.

You will have two functions for controlling the add to cart buttons. Proper placement/execution of the code will yield different results. Please see code snippets below.

The first one is found in /catalog/view/javascript/common.js:

```
function addToCart(product_id) {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
```

The second one is typically found in /catalog/view/theme/template/**yourtheme**/product/product.tpl:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
```

If you will notice the **data:** parts of the code. One is checking for options and then adding to cart and the other is just adding to cart.

This snippet of code `data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),`
is checking for options and then adding to cart. This is typically used on the product detail page (product.tpl). 
This snippet of code `data: 'product_id=' + product_id,` is directly adding the product to cart and is typically used elsewhere on the site (other than product detail page). Where the user can just add the item to the cart and then checkout.

The reason you are getting *2x items* added to the cart is because you are using the snippet of code that checks for options and then adds to cart. To make any add to cart button only place one item in the cart (without checking for options) you will need to use `data: 'product_id=' + product_id,`

It will look like this

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
type: 'post',
data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(json) {
```